# ionic2 ion-radio can not be set to checked, by using below codes

Tags: ionic2

Can not be set to checked, by using below codes, anyone can help me?

1

```
    <ion-radio checked="true" value="go"></ion-radio>
```

2

```
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="status">
       <ion-list-header>Status</ion-list-header>
       <ion-radio (click)="changeStatus('0')" value="0">
        Status 0
       </ion-radio>
       <ion-radio (click)="changeStatus('1')" value="1">   
          Status 1
       </ion-radio>
       <ion-radio (click)="changeStatus('2')" value="2"> 
          Status 2
        </ion-radio>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="status">
   <ion-list-header>Status</ion-list-header>
   <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Status 0</ion-label>
   <ion-radio (click)="changeStatus('0')" value="0">  
   </ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Status 1</ion-label>
   <ion-radio (click)="changeStatus('1')" value="1">   
   </ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Status 2</ion-label>
   <ion-radio (click)="changeStatus('2')" value="2"> 
    </ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks

**Update:**

In your address-list.html

```
<div class="address-list">
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="recipientId"> 
        <!-- <ion-list-header> 请选择地址： </ion-list-header>  -->
        <ion-item *ngFor="#item of addresses">
            <ion-label>
                <h2 class="text-big text-color-light-grey">{{item.name}}，{{item.phone}}</h2>
                <p class="text-thin text-color-light-grey">{{item.provice}} &nbsp;{{item.city}}</p>
                <p class="text-thin text-color-light-grey descr">{{recipientId}} == {{item.id}} - {{item.street}} {{item.address}}</p>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-radio (click)="selectAddress(item.id)" value="item.id"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

And in address-list.ts:

```
selectAddress(itemId) {
        this.recipientId = itemId;
    }
```

Comment: change to as yours, still not work, please refer to https://github.com/aaronchen2k/mobistore-client/blob/master/app/pages/address/address-list.html

Comment: Sir, I had a look at the code.. As per my understanding (correct me if I am wrong), you have a list of radio buttons and when you check an item (i.e the radio button) on the list you have a function in the ts file that will get and change the value of a variable right..?

Comment: I just update the codes in github, now the question is that can't select the saved address by default when open address-list.html page,  thanks.